# jquery delay does not work as expected

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
function sliderStop(id, value) {

    $(this).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').delay(500).fadeOut().delay(500);

    $('#' + id).val(value);
    __doPostBack(id, '');
}
```

I'm using the jquery ui-slider - this is the function called via the stop event.

I'm creating a postback for the control which works fine, but I want to fade the out tooltip out before calling the postback. The delay works on its own but doesn't seem to work when I add the postback code - I'm guessing it just posts back straight away I don't see the fade out.

If I remove the postback code, I can see the delay.

Any ideas how this might be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the callback of the `fadeOut` to wait for it to complete:

```
$(this).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').delay(500).fadeOut(function() {
    $('#' + id).val(value);
    __doPostBack(id, '');
});
```

Comment: I guess you could remove the second delay() ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff - The answer works, so no need for the second delay any more